# Opening encrypted pictures

Tags: file, encryption, image

I have created an algorithm do Encrypt and Decrypt files, I have tested with .bmp and I would like to open an encrypted picture to detect patterns.
Is there any linux program to open corrupted pictures?
I really want to see my generated trash.

Thanks ;-)
Henrique Rocha

Comment: I wouldn't think that this is possible as all the headers are probably destroyed. Try with a text file instead.

Comment: I have replaced the encrypted headers with the original, It worked.
Yum yum, nice trash!

Comment: And the whole purpose of your experiment is to show what?

Comment: @soulseekah I presume it is an attempt to replicate the sorts of images shown on http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_modes_of_operation. Scroll down and look for the penguins.

Comment: @HenriqueRocha Either delete your question or post your own answer, so that others know this is no longer an issue. Given the question and the solution, I would suggest you just delete it.